# Bootstrap columns stack vertically when their total columns is equal to 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the [Offsetting Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex8&stacked=h) example from [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) a first column has `col-sm-5` and a second column has the same `col-sm-5` but also an offset `col-sm-offset-2`. As the total of their bootstrap grid's columns is 5+(5+2)=12 this is suppoed to make be aligned horizontally for small screens and not being stacked vertically as the result shows. Why does it happen ? I even tried to remove the extra offset but nothing has changed.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6" style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-5 .col-md-6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0" style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-5 .col-sm-offset-2 .col-md-6 .col-md-offset-0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working as expected to me, are you trying to target the smallest screens? If so, try -xs- instead of -sm-?

Comment: you are right and i didn't know that for sm screens the columns width is 12 by default